# How Can I select drop-down values using different buttons ID

Tags: javascript, html

I have four lists and four buttons. I want to auto-select each list separately for each button.

```html
<select class="aa" required="" name="f1990" {input.multiple}="" {input.size}="" id="f1990" placeholder="" data-required="true">
    <option value="897">Athens - 5 days / 4 nights - Total Tax: $132.44</option>
    <option value="896">Atlanta - 4 days / 3 nights - Total Tax: $99.75</option>
    <option value="895">Atlantic City - 4 days / 3 nights - Total Tax: $89.10</option>
    <option value="894">Bali - 8 days / 7 nights - Total Tax: $196.84</option>
</select>




<button id="1"> Redeem </button>
<button id="2"> Redeem </button>
<button id="3"> Redeem </button>
<button id="4"> Redeem </button>
```

Comment: Okay, what have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: Those aren't lists, they select options. A list would be `<ol>`, `<ul>`, or `<dl>`

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what you need? Do you need each element of the <select> to be selected depending on which button the user clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a neat solution to the problem

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.aa')
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', handler))

let mapOptions = { "1": "897", "2": "896", "3": "895", "4": "894" }

function handler(ev) {
  select.value = mapOptions[ev.target.id]
}
```

```html
<select class="aa" required="" name="f1990" {input.multiple}="" {input.size}="" id="f1990" placeholder="" data-required="true">
    <option value="897">Athens - 5 days / 4 nights - Total Tax: $132.44</option>
    <option value="896">Atlanta - 4 days / 3 nights - Total Tax: $99.75</option>
    <option value="895">Atlantic City - 4 days / 3 nights - Total Tax: $89.10</option>
    <option value="894">Bali - 8 days / 7 nights - Total Tax: $196.84</option>
</select>




<button id="1"> Redeem </button>
<button id="2"> Redeem </button>
<button id="3"> Redeem </button>
<button id="4"> Redeem </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the value attribute to match options and buttons.

```js
let cities = document.getElementById("f1990")
        document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(b => b.addEventListener("click", function setRedeem(e) {
            cities.value = e.target.value
        }, false))
```

```html
<select class="aa" required="" name="f1990" {input.multiple}="" {input.size}="" id="f1990" placeholder=""
        data-required="true">
        <option value="897">Athens - 5 days / 4 nights - Total Tax: $132.44</option>
        <option value="896">Atlanta - 4 days / 3 nights - Total Tax: $99.75</option>
        <option value="895">Atlantic City - 4 days / 3 nights - Total Tax: $89.10</option>
        <option value="894">Bali - 8 days / 7 nights - Total Tax: $196.84</option>
    </select>

    <button id="1" value="897"> Redeem </button>
    <button id="2" value="896"> Redeem </button>
    <button id="3" value="895"> Redeem </button>
    <button id="4" value="894"> Redeem </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with selectedIndex if the index of the buttons matches the index of the options (see option 1 - selectOptionByIndex).

Or, add value attributes to the buttons that match the values for the options (option 2 - selectOptionByValue).

**Demo**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-r4vuzj

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    var value = item.getAttribute("value");
    selectOptionByIndex(index);  // option 1
    selectOptionByValue(value);  // option 2
  })
})

function selectOptionByIndex(index) {
  var select = (document.getElementById('mySelect')) as HTMLSelectElement;
  select.selectedIndex = index;
}

function selectOptionByValue(value) {
  var select = (document.getElementById('mySelect')) as HTMLSelectElement;
  select.value = value;
}
```

With the second option - select by value - just add the same value attribute to the buttons as follows:

```
<select id="mySelect" class="aa" required="" name="f1990" {input.multiple}="" {input.size}="" id="f1990" placeholder="" data-required="true">
    <option value="897">Athens - 5 days / 4 nights - Total Tax: $132.44</option>
    <option value="896">Atlanta - 4 days / 3 nights - Total Tax: $99.75</option>
    <option value="895">Atlantic City - 4 days / 3 nights - Total Tax: $89.10</option>
    <option value="894">Bali - 8 days / 7 nights - Total Tax: $196.84</option>
</select>

<br>

<button id="1" value="897" name="btn"> Redeem </button>
<button id="2" value="896" name="btn"> Redeem </button>
<button id="3" value="895" name="btn"> Redeem </button>
<button id="4" value="894" name="btn"> Redeem </button>
```